# A binary relation contained in its square

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, relations, directed-graphs

My colleague (I guess, investigating structure of specific semigroups) is looking for references about binary relations $R\subset X\times X$ such that $R\subset R\circ R$, that is for each $(v,u)\in R$ there exists $w\in X$ such that $(v,w)\in R$ and $(w,v)\in R$.

The issue has an equivalent graph theoretical formulation. A directed (not necessarily finite) graph $G$ has no parallel edges, but can have loops and for each edge $(v,u)$ of $G$ there exists a vertex $w$ of $G$ (which can coincide with $v$ or $u$) such that both $(v,w)$ and $(w,u)$ are edges of $G$.

Thanks.

Comment: What are parallel edges?

Comment: @WilliamElliot The respective restriction means that for each vertices $v,u$ (including a case $v=u$) of $G$  there exists at most one edge from $v$ to $u$.

Answer (score 1):

An order $(S,\le)$ is order dense when
for all $a,b$ in $S$, exists $x$ with $a \le x$, $x \le b$.

Based upon that I would consider a relation $R$
with $R$ subset $R\circ R$ to be a dense relation.